# Teams: "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again." in loop

Tags: linux, office365, microsoft-teams

I'm currently setting up my work system and totally lost at getting Microsoft Teams running. Other Microsoft Office products (like Excel, Office, Word) are working seamlessly for both native and web version, and for now only Teams seems to not work (also for both native and web).

Whenever I try to sign into Teams there's a redirection loop:

```
↱ https://teams.microsoft.com/go#
↳ https://teams.microsoft.com/go#id_token=xxx&session_state=xxx
```

... until being redirected back to the login page after about 10 seconds with the vacuous message:

```
We couldn't sign you in. Please try again.
```

It's working on a colleague's system, so it's not an account or licence issue.

I googled it, tried Chromium, Firefox, Opera, several packages like the widely-used `teams-for-linux` and even the official client for Insiders, `ms-teams`, tried both AUR and Snapcraft packages, and even built them myself - nothing worked. It's always the same behavior as described above.

I'm using the i3 community edition of Manjaro (freshly installed).

I'd be very thankful for any kind of ideas.

Comment: Try re-syncing the time with an internet time server. Question: Did you change the password just before this started?

Comment: Oh my... yes indeed, I always use UTC on my devices and usually leave other things default. I set them equal and everything works now. Man! I would have NEVER guessed that without your input. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between your computer and that of your colleague is most likely
that of the clock.

I suggest to re-sync the time on your computer with an internet time server.

Comment: thanks, same issue ubuntu , pity this question is not more available to the error phrase 'Teams: "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again.' redirect . I had it in connection with https://superuser.com/questions/1470765/ms-teams-the-request-is-not-properly-formatted-the-parameter-login-hint-is-d from the error logs on background

Comment: As this issue is gaining more attention, I updated the title to a more fitting one. Hopefully users will find their way to this thread sooner now.

Comment: Wow, it really was! When my laptop ran out of battery it apparently started running 3000 seconds fast of NTP. A quick `chronyc makestep` to cancel the slew and force the clock to the right time solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue, you can execute these commands (Tested on ArchLinux):

We will activate the service, to activate synchronization between the computer and the servers on the internet:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service
```

We start the service :

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

Comment: @MMM Sorry, I updated the comment ^^

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Tried resetting TZ, spoofing my browser user-agent to seem like it came from a Windows PC etc etc.

None of these fixes worked and I continued having the issue on both web and desktop app.

I finally fixed it by resetting my DNS Nameserver. Here is a [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to doing this on the more recent Ubuntu releases. Maybe it helps someone...

I used an OpenDNS server address i.e. 208.67.222.222

Alternatively 8.8.8.8